# Pass Javascript variable to PHP using Hidden Input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In the below codes what I am trying to do is send the total value amount of ticket then from Javascript to PHP the `action_page.php` is the receiver but the problem is every time the Reserve Button is clicked it sends `0` while at the  same time when a user chooses a seat and if I use `window.alert(b);` to display the currently selected value it shows without any problem. The problem only appears when using the button to send the values to PHP from Javascript.

Where am I wrong? Below are the codes

```
    ss.php  //main page

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Seat(s)</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
$b=0;


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //Seat Reserve

        require 'action_page.php';

    }

     elseif (isset($_POST[''])) { //Cancel

        require 'mypage.php';

    }
}



?>

    <h2>Please choose a seat to book</h2>
    <form action="ss.php" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A1" value="100">$100<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A2" value="65"> $65<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A3" value="55"> $55<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="A4" value="50"> $50<br>

      <p id="demo">
        Selected Seat(s)
        <br>
        <span id="selected-seats"></span> <!-- container for selected seats -->
        <br>
        Total: <span id="total-container"></span> USD  

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" onClick="displayCheck()">Reserve Now</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="value" value="0">
      </p>
    </form>






<script>
const selections = {};
const inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
const totalElem = document.getElementById("total-container");
const seatsElem = document.getElementById("selected-seats");

for (let i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox") {
        inputElems[i].addEventListener("click", displayCheck);
    }   
}

function displayCheck(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        selections[e.target.id] = {
            id: e.target.id,
            value: e.target.value
        };
    }
    else {
        delete selections[e.target.id];
    }

    const result = [];
    let total = 0;

    for (const key in selections) {
        result.push(selections[key].id);
        total += parseInt(selections[key].value);
    }

    totalElem.innerText = total;
    seatsElem.innerHTML = result.join(",");
   //window.alert(result);   //Hold Number of Seats Selected.
   //window.alert(total);  //Hold Total Cost of Selected Seats.

var b = <?php echo $b; ?> + total ;
document.getElementsByName("value").value = b;


window.alert(b);   //Hold Number of Seats Selected.



}

    </script>





  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
action_page.php //For receiving value from ss.php

<html>
<head>
<title>Seats Feedback</title>
</head>

<body>


<?php

echo "<br>";

$myval = $_POST['value'];

print_r($myval);  

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
...
// Move the `onClick` function all to `onsubmit` in the form tag. 
<form onsubmit="displayCheck();" action="ss.php" method="post">
...
var b = <?php echo $b; ?> + total ;
document.getElementsByName("value")[0].value = b; //<-- Notice the selection of first array
window.alert(b);   // Will display the total value of selected seats.

}
...
```

**How and Why?**: When you are executing the page `ss.php` , you are setting the value of `$b` as `0`, so until the value is changed inside `php` for that execution, the value will remain the same.

So when the above page renders, the values of `$b` are echoed as below.

```
...
 <input type="hidden" name="value" value="0">
...
 var b = 0 + total ;
...
```

Now this is where the job of php ie. [Backend] is done and is handed over to `javaScript (js)` ie. [Frontend].

Now on frontend when you do your calculation, the value of the `<input>` is still `0`. Where as the value of the variable `b` has been updated. So in order to pass that new value of `b` with the form, you will have to update the value of the `<input>`.

Hence the "Solution"..

[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/QBvMvg?editors=1010)

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested but same results, I have updated above codes please can you check where i am wrong @9KSoft

Comment: Most probably, your form is being posted even before you could update the value of the field named `value`. You will have to prevent the automatic posting of that form and do it manually OR try looking into using Ajax to post your form. M on mobile right now, so maybe will update when back on my work station.

Comment: Let me try manually, if you will update when you are on your work station will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, it was my bad, had overlooked that the selector `document.getElementsByName` returns an array and we have to select the first element. Alternatively you could use `getElementById` and give your input an `id` its a lot easier that way, and lesser margin for errors. Also I'd recommend that once you are comfortable with js, you look into `jQuery`, it will make your work a lot easier.

Comment: Oooh i got the point now, Thanks much again let me work on it @9KSoft